# Can someone explain this phenomenon when overwriting the first line of a text file?

Tags: c#, overwrite, file-writing

I'm working on a project where a user can view sentence phrases and select the particular meaning of a particular word in the sentence (best way to describe it). Part of what I need to do is save the index of the current sentence selected, so that upon reopening the program, the user can return from where they left off. That was easy.

However, I have an issue when trying to overwrite the first line of the file that saves their work (it contains the index of the last sentence viewed), namely that it erases the next line (partially or otherwise). The best (ie only) solution I've found so far is to rewrite the entire file, but I'd still like to know what's going on under the hood.

Essentially it, I first wrote the following to a text file:

```
Andrew
ate
breakfast
```

Then I overwrote the first line with 'Andrew 122' with WriteLine, and got the following:

```
Andrew 122
breakfast
```

Using Write, I got this:

```
Andrew 122e
breakfast
```

Is there anyone who can explain to me what's going on?

(for reference, here's the code I used to test this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = String.Format(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\{0} Project\test.txt", @"C#");
        if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Delete(path);

        WriteToFile(path, true, "Andrew", "ate", "breakfast");
        WriteToFile(path, false, "Andrew 122");
    }

public static void WriteToFile(string path, bool newLine, params string[] line)
    {
        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter fWriter = new StreamWriter(fStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                if (newLine)
                    fWriter.WriteLine(line[i]);
                else
                    fWriter.Write(line[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot add additional characters in the middle of a file. You have to read the whole file and write it bck with changes.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen that is not true. In fact that is exactly what is happening. The new line and "at" are being replaced by "122"

Comment: You didn't insert any new line when you were writing to the file.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Sorry for bad eypression/explanation. You explained it much better in your answer. Of course you can write in the middle of a file, but you cannot add something or replace 6 characters (Andrew) with 9 characters (Andrew122) and keep the remaining part as it is.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen ok, gotcha now, agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "phenomenon" is that you are thinking of the file in human terms, where you see line breaks, but the `StreamWriter` is operating on bytes. You initially have this series of bytes (notice the carriage return and new line):

```
[A][n][d][r][e][w][\r][\n][a][t][e][\r][\n][b][r][e][a][k][f][a][s][t]
```

Then you overwrite bytes 7-10 with " 122"

```
[A][n][d][r][e][w][  ][ 1][2][2][e][\r][\n][b][r][e][a][k][f][a][s][t]
```

Comment: I had a suspicion that it might have had something to do with that. I actually found a way to overwrite the first line, which was to add a bunch of spaces to the first line initially, then pad the new line with more spaces so that the length of the line remains the same.